# Performance: multiple Webmethods or multiple web-services

Tags: java, c#, performance, web-services, wcf

Would there be any impact on performances by having more Webmethods in a single web service. Or is it advisable to create new web-service for each Webmethod

Comment: Why you have such assumption? Performance only decided by your web method itself, it should have nothing to do with webmethod's number.

Comment: Because I was told the current web service has lots of performance issue and the team wanted a brand new service. Which I believe it’s not needed the Webmethods would suffice. But wanted to get expert opinions as well 

Comment: Then you can convince yourself by making a simple test. Calling the same web method, one is with original version. the other is with `shrink version`(which only contains this web method)